# How can I use Pacemaker to setup a virtual IP for receiving syslog messages?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, syslog

I need to setup a VIP / floating IP that network devices will send their syslog messages to. The idea behind the VIP is to have a highly available setup in an attempt to minimize the amount of logs lost as a result of the syslog server being down.

This is going to be done in a CentOS 7 environment so I figure I can either have `rsyslog` listen for remote messages on the floating address or setup syslog-ng on an alternate port (such as `5514`) solely for receiving the network messages.

My research tells me that [Pacemaker](http://clusterlabs.org/wiki/Pacemaker) should be able to do this but I am not quite sure how. Any tips on the actual how part would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have this configuration along with `syslog-ng`, which I believe is needed as `syslog` itself doesn't allow receiving remote messages.

There is an `ocf` primitive called `IPaddr2` whose syntax is similar to this:

```
primitive virtual_ip ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 \
        params ip="192.168.1.100" cidr_netmask="32" nic="eth0" \
        op monitor interval="30s" timeout="20s" \
        meta target-role="Started"
```

It is self explanatory, however, to see all the parameters you can check the help within the `crm` command.

Comment: So, do you just tell syslog-ng to listen for messages on 192.168.1.100 on both nodes? Is there any health checking of syslog-ng being done or is it based on the node being available? I am new to clustering like this so please bear with me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, exactly, but not just listen, but also configure it as a cluster resource. This way you make sure that it only runs where the VIP is currently configured. You can configure syslog-ng as a LSB resource but be careful, the LSB script that installs the package on Ubuntu is not Pacemaker LSB compliant, I don't know in CentOS. In any case you can customize the LSB script to make it LSB compliant.

Comment: That makes sense. One last question: would I be right in assuming that I would need to make a group out of the IPaddr2 and syslog-ng resources? It seems both are available via the heartbeat provider ( https://github.com/ClusterLabs/resource-agents/blob/master/heartbeat/syslog-ng)

Comment: Yep, that would be a good idea since both will be running on the same machine and one without the other doesn't make sense, so a group is convenient here